# How to configure the wcf service to view the test page without pointing to svc file in address box?

Tags: wcf, app-config, endpoint

I have created a working wcf service. I have come a cross a page regarding wcf services
which describes the process for eliminating default wcf service page.

It is here https://github.com/geersch/WcfServiceMessage

Except for the things the author of this page is describing, I have one question.

How has he managed to configure the IIS or Web.config to host page with the address: http://localhost:8732/HelloWorld/ ?

At home, the only address I see my service at is: http://localhost:8732/MyServiceName.svc
(with svc extension)

How has he done it that the endpoint address: "HellowWorld" is used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The WCF service endpoint is not actually a file. The total url itself is what the server recognizes as something to service, so the HelloWorld piece is just as good as HelloWorld.svc.

This is a difference between IIS hosted service and Windows or Visual Studio service host (cassini). In iis, you do have to specify a file that ends with svc and make that extension known. In iis you can also set a svc file as the default file to open if a specific directory is opened. that way you can achieve the same behavior.